# Nextjs Cypress Only found unit test code coverage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cypress, code-coverage, istanbul

I am trying to add code coverage to cypress following this [tutorial](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Introduction)

I added `@cypress/code-coverage` and `babel-plugin-istanbul` to my `package.json` file below

```
{
  "name": "quiz",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "cypress": "cypress open"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.0.10",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.49.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.9.12",
    "@types/node": "17.0.15",
    "@types/react": "17.0.39",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.1.1",
    "cypress": "^9.4.1",
    "eslint": "8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.10",
    "typescript": "4.5.5"
  }
}
```

I configured my `cypress/support/index.js`

```
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands'

// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
```

I configured my `cypress/plugins/index.js`

```
/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config)
  on('file:preprocessor', require('@cypress/code-coverage/use-babelrc'))
  return config
}
```

My `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "istanbul"
  ]
}
```

After I run my test I get the following message

```
Only found unit test code coverage. [@cypress/code-coverage]
```

[image]

After I run my `quiz.spec.js` test, I run

```
npx nyc report --reporter=text-summary
```

And get an empty coverage summary

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

My [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/quiz)

Comment: What is in your `.babelrc`?

Comment: @Fody added `.babelrc`

Comment: I just ran your repo, coverage report gave `88.13% Statements 52/59, 90.9% Branches 20/22, 93.75% Functions 15/16, 87.27% Lines 48/55`

Comment: I deleted package.lock and init with `yarn`

Comment: @Fody I deleted `package-lock.json` and ran `npm i` again and got the same results as you, if you submit your comment as an answer I will glad give the +10 points!

Comment: @dev_el, I wish you had not removed your repo. I would help me to fine my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76540630

Comment: @HamidMayeli I made the repo public now, maybe that can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was just a node_modules problem, as your repo worked after download and initialization. I think babel can fail silently if it's dependencies are out of order.

I removed `package.lock` (because I use `yarn` to manage things) and then `yarn` to init the dependecies.