# How to add code coverage to React/NextJs/Typescript (create-next-app) with cypress

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, cypress, code-coverage

I created a new project with `create-next-app` and the default options.

```bash
npx create-next-app@13.4.7
---
Would you like to use TypeScript with this project? Yes
Would you like to use ESLint with this project? Yes
Would you like to use Tailwind CSS with this project? Yes
Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? Yes
Use App Router (recommended)? Yes
Would you like to customize the default import alias? No
```

And then added `Cypress` by following [the nextjs doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/testing#manual-setup).

Then I tried to add code coverage to it by following [the cypress doc for CC](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Using-code-transpilation-pipeline).

But it results in compile error, as the project uses `SWC` while the CC docs uses `babel`.

As I already build the project, I am facing with the following error

```html
Failed to compile

./src/app/layout.tsx:2:1
Syntax error: "next/font" requires SWC although Babel is being used due to a custom babel config being present.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/babel-font-loader-conflict

This error occurred during the build process and can only be dismissed by fixing the error.
```

The key files in my project are:
`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "cypress": "cypress open",
    "e2e": "start-server-and-test dev http://localhost:3000 \"cypress open --e2e\"",
    "e2e:headless": "start-server-and-test dev http://localhost:3000 \"cypress run --e2e\"",
    "component": "cypress open --component",
    "component:headless": "cypress run --component"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.3.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.6",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.7",
    "next": "13.4.7",
    "postcss": "8.4.24",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.10.7",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.1.1",
    "cypress": "^12.15.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

cypress.config.ts

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: "next",
      bundler: "webpack",
    },
    setupNodeEvents: (on, config) => {
      require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config)
      return config
    },
  },

  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',
    setupNodeEvents: (on, config) => {
      require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config)
      return config
    },
  },
});
```

`cypress/support/commands.ts`:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
```

`.babelrc`: The commented part comes from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71152128/nextjs-cypress-only-found-unit-test-code-coverage).

```json
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": ["transform-class-properties", "istanbul"]
}
// {
//     "presets": [
//       "next/babel"
//     ],
//     "plugins": [
//       "istanbul"
//     ]
// }
```

`tsconfig.ts`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

You can clone the repo [here](https://github.com/hamidmayeli/react-nextjs-cypress-codecoverage).

I also, tried [swc-plugin-coverage-instrument](https://github.com/hamidmayeli/react-nextjs-cypress-codecoverage/tree/use-swc-plugin-coverage-instrument) but the `__coverage__` does not exist when I m testing.

### What I need

What I like to have is a `React`/`NextJs` project with `Typescript` and `Code Coverage`. `Cypress` is preferred test lib.

Comment: Did you mean to link to [swc-plugin-coverage-instrument](https://github.com/kwonoj/swc-plugin-coverage-instrument)?

Comment: @FayFulbright yes I have tried that in another branch and I provided the link

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** Another problem surfaced. I use Storybook and the Storybook build had a problem with there already being a babel.config.js in the root. After wrestling with it for a bit, I decided remove the babel.config.js altogether which reverted the Next.js app to SWC. Thus no more coverge!

I think unless Next.js officially supports coverage collection through SWC, there's no point trying to revert to Babel to get it.

---

The swc coverage plugin configured in `experimental` block in `next.config.js` did not work for me. The app would keep crashing and the coverage generated would only be for `next.config.js`

With `babel.config.js` I proceeded exactly as you did but removed next/font from the app (it is part of the scaffolded app and is used for Google Inter font). So far everything is working fine.

Clearly this is not a very good hack (relying on Babel when it was replaced with SWC nearly a year ago, not knowing what else besides next/font might be broken down the line). But I am not using it in production code. So I'll see how far I can go with it.

I considered moving to Vite. The only thing that prevented me was that about 8-10 months ago when I looked at it, although the dev server was super fast, it didn't seem to have a production grade bundler config. With Next.js on the other hand, a production grade Webpack config that is kept optimised/updated is a big part of the value proposition.

Hope Next.js sort out the issue with SWC-based builds (default since v13) not allowing coverage collection.